# rmarkdown hide tidylog messages after customisation

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use `tidylog` in `Rstudio` which I customise to green to distinguish its messages from other colours (e.g., errors which are in orange):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(crayon)
library(tidylog)
crayon_col <- function(x) cat(green$bold(x), sep = "\n")
options("tidylog.display" = list(crayon_col))
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise(mean(Sepal.Width))
```

[image]

However, when I include this customization in `rmarkdown`, it no longer recognises the output as a message and so when I want to hide its output in a chunk, `message = FALSE` doesnt work:

````
---
title: "tmp"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(crayon)
library(tidylog)
#when I remove the next two lines, message = FALSE works
crayon_col <- function(x) cat(green$bold(x), sep = "\n")
options("tidylog.display" = list(crayon_col))
```

# show tidylog output

```{r showtidylog}
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Sepal.Width))
```


# hide tidylog output

```{r hidetidylog, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Sepal.Width))
```
````

If I remove the following lines, it works:

```
crayon_col <- function(x) cat(green$bold(x), sep = "\n")
options("tidylog.display" = list(crayon_col))
```

Is it possible to keep this customisation but let `rmarkdown` recognise it is still a message?

Thanks